# How do I change my controller so it is decoupled enough from my view?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, jsp, model-view-controller

I'm programming a web app using Spring MVC where I need to create some elements that I cannot create directly through jsp. Specifically all of those that list values that I get from my database, since I cannot create a structure in jsp before knowing its size. Here's how I'm doing it right now:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getAllEjercicios (...)

...

Table table = new Table("table_ejercicios", "table_ejercicios", new ArrayList<TableHead>(Arrays.asList(tH1, tH2, tH3)), getEjercicioTableContent(ejercicioList));

...

model.put("table", table.getCode());

return new ModelAndView("ejercicio/ejercicio-list", MODEL_NAME, model);
```

This is my controller method, where Table is a custom class that I created that will return the html code of the table when calling getCode(), using the parameters it was given. The problem with this is that I'm starting to see my Controller is not decoupled enough, since it's passing the view the HTML code of the entire object instead of just the parameters I need in order to build it in my jsp file. Btw, this is not just an issue with this particular table, I have other dropdown lists and things as such in my code.

The problem is that if I use a javascript function which receives the same parameters as my table inside the jsp, I'll have to replicate a lot of code in other views that use similar tables, since I'll have to copy the entire javascript function in each jsp file.

My code works perfectly, it's not a problem of it not working, it's a problem of structure.

What should I do, should I keep my code as it is, or is there a solution I'm not thinking of?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html pages, contains lots of elements, such as tables, forms, dropdown,... . If you generate all UI elements in the backend, your server side code will full of client side coding! This is not a good practice as you already know.

I think the best practice is rendering html pages without any extra UI elements, just html code with data. You can even exclude data from page and fill html elements with data from ajax request. However, your controller will completely free from UI codes. With this approach, your concern is **duplication of codes in the client side**. This can be solved with **generating javascript utilities**. For example, you have same html table structure in multiple pages. For doing this, you can write a javascript function for generating table. This function can take some parameters and add dynamic table to every page you need. You can do similar works for other elements such as forms and dropdown.

Comment: I've been doing that, now I have all my html related code in jsp and js auxiliary files (I use my js functions to dynamically generate elements like tables or collections of other elements) and it's working perfectly! Now my controllers are completely decoupled from the html code, they just send data in JSON format and the rest is handled in my view. Thank you for your answer!